# How to import local module with same name as sys modul?

Tags: python, pyzmq

I've compiled pyzmq (python zeromq binding) module and want to use that one instead system one.

How to skip module loading from system so that my import zmq first searches in current folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By installing it in a location that is listed earlier in `sys.path`.

The directory your project is in, for example, is always listed first in `sys.path` and other packages in the same directory will be found before system locations. In other words, put `pyzmq` in the same folder as your script and it'll Just Work.

You can also add entries to `sys.path` by listing them in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable; these will be inserted into `sys.path` before system locations.